# how to pass the arguments to the bash script which is called inside a vagrantfile?

Tags: ruby, vagrant

In the vagrant file there is a call made to the bash script. Now, i want to pass the arguments to the bash script which are actually read from a yaml file following is the snippet

```
  yaml_hash = YAML.load_file('config.yml')
  p yaml_hash['servers']
  yaml_hash['servers'].each do |letter, hash|
     p letter
     p hash['ip']
     p hash['pass']
     controller.vm.provision :shell, keep_color: true, path: '/controller.sh', :args => [p hash['ip'], p hash['pass']]
  end
```

But the above piece is "syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting keyword_end" i am not getting what is going on wrong i have tried by giving the quotes around the argument also but of no use. Please suggest how to pass the arguments to the bash file.

Answer (score 1):

The method [`p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) prints its argument to the output. You don't need to print the values but to pass them as arguments to the script. Remove `p` from the list of arguments:

```
 controller.vm.provision :shell, keep_color: true, path: '/controller.sh',
     :args => [hash['ip'], hash['pass']]
```